# Using custom fonts in an expo app using react-native-navigation

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fonts, expo

As you can see in the code for adding custom fonts from the official expo website, the onLayoutRootView function is executed in onLayout, in View:

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
    'Inter-Black': require('./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.otf'),
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded || fontError) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);

  if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 30 }}>Inter Black</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Platform Default</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

In my application I want to use react-native-navigation and cover my screens with onLayoutRootView, but adding View with onLayout={onLayoutRootView} ends up showing a blank screen. I also tried adding onLayout to the NavigationContainer, but then the onLayoutRootView function does not execute correctly.

Thank you in advance for your help.